# It appears that comments can not be deleted in https mode in tor.stackexchange.com Web page

Tags: bug, https, comments

My observation indicates that comments can not be deleted in https mode in tor.Stackexchange.com Web page. One need to go to unsecured mode to be able to delete a comment. Have anybody else observed this phenomenon? If so what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that not *all* of our APIs and endpoints are fully ready for SSL. While *almost everything* works, and works well, there's a few things left that have to be finished before we call it officially supported.

It's not just throwing more certs at things, when you get into load balanced / highly available setups like the one we have, then add socket servers and the like on top of it to enable all the real-time stuff, a lot of core code that wasn't written anticipating TLS has to be revisited.

It shouldn't be long, though :)

Comment: Dear, would you please announce it when it is done.